# Disable removable device notification for hard drives

Tags: mount, notification-area

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with two hard drives.

The second drive is set to mount to `/home/myuser/DATA` and it mounts OK. However gnome shows a 'Removable Devices' item in notification area which lists my hard drive with the unmount button.

How do I make Ubuntu to treat the second hdd like the system one, without suggesting me to unmount it in the notification area?

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question, as I have the same problem with LUKS encrypted drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the mount point to /mnt/"something". Modify your fstab and it shouldn't show the unmount option any longer.

Then you may bind mount it to the directory you want:

```
UUID=your_uuid_here /mnt/DATA ext4       defaults        0       2
/mnt/DATA             /home/yrogirg/DATA   none bind 0 0
```

Comment: Can't test this, because my LUKS partition is mounted as `/` and cannot be relocated.

Comment: hm @zigg I haven't tried that yet, because I don't need mounting to `/mnt` either. But what if mounting to `/mnt` and then bind mount to `/` ?

Comment: It worked for me, To Do, I've edited your answer a bit to include bind mount fstab line. and there is a typo, it should be "UUID"

Comment: I know this answer is old... FWIW, I do not believe that this works in newer versions of Ubuntu (ex 21). I tried mounting to /mnt/xxx but it still shows up in the "Removable Devices" UI.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the GNOME people are already aware of this; see this bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660595

(For now, though, it's sufficiently annoying to me that I'd like to see a workaround, hence the bounty.)

Answer (score -1):

Modify your /etc/fstab adding a line as follows:

```
UUID=[your second hdd UUID] /               ext3    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0       1
```

You may want to change "/" with a different mount point or ext3 with the correct file system.

Comment: how does it supposed to solve the problem? Is it because of 1? or user_xattr?

Comment: Just try and tell me if it works... It's a combo between those options.

Comment: It doesn't work for LUKS devices.  My encrypted partition, which is already on `/` and already has an `fstab` entry with a pass number of 1 (FWIW: the pass number is used by `fsck` to determine the order of filesystem checks at boot time), still shows as a removable drive.  I'm not totally sure what `user_xattr` was supposed to do for this anyway.

Comment: 2 more hints. 1) Try with pysdm (it's a fstab GUI editor). 2) looking in /sys/block/ I saw two files that could be help: /sys/block/sda/removable (it contains 0) and /sys/block/sr0/removable (it contains 1).

Comment: With all due respect, I don't need an editor for `fstab`; I've been `vi`-ing them for a decade and a half. ;)  `removable` on my LUKS root partition (`dm-0`) reads `0`.  If you look at the GNOME bug I linked in my answer, I think they're more paralyzed by their inability to get a reliable answer as to what's removable and what isn't rather than not knowing where to look.  I simply need a way to manually mark a volume as nonremovable that GNOME respects.

Comment: So only the Gnome notifier is wrongly detecting as removable... It seems that other users having this issue with kde 4.7 solved it with the upgrading to 4.8, and F16->F17... Your gnome version?

Comment: 3.4, which shipped with precise.  IIRC, this has been around at least oneiric.  It's also a problem in Unity because it uses GNOME components; you can see the "removable" drives appear in the dock.  I have no idea what the impact is with KDE.

Comment: You're referring to an icon in the notification area. Is the problem related to a specific extension for gnome shell or the unity ejecter indicator or both?

Comment: In gnome-shell, there's icon in the notification area titled "Removable Devices" that these appear under, they show up in the Unity dock, and the drives also appear in Devices in Nautilus (file manager) as ejectable.  It's part of the standard plumbing; what component, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm afraid that we (you) will have to wait for the next release in the GNOME 3 series, that is scheduled for 24 September 2012. However you could try to go with the live development version (currently in a very early 3.5.1) to see if the problem is being handled: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Download-GNOME-3-5-1-Live-USB-ISO-Image-270436.shtml