# How to mount a subdirectory of `/home` without making it appear as removable?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount, fstab

In my present configuration, my `/home` lives on a regular spinning hard drive, with the exception of `/home/mac/runtime` which is a partition from a SSD.

My problem is that such partition shows up as a "removable device" even if the mount options are such that is not possible for the user to unmount it at all (besides, it is not a *removable* device, given that it is a partition of an internal hard drive!).

**Indeed my goal would be for the partition layout to be totally transparent** (my `/boot` is on another disk too, but the user wouldn't know, and the `/boot` doesn't appear as a removable drive).

The portion of my `/etc/fstab` of interest looks like this:

```
# /home was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=<my-uuid-here>  /home              ext4  noatime,nodiratime   0  2  
# /home/mac/runtime was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=<my-uuid-here>  /home/mac/runtime  ext4  noatime,nodiratime   0  2
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What happens for / ?

Comment: @jasmines - Not sure I got your question right. Hope this is what you want to know: `/` works as expected (it doesn't show up as a removable drive). Physically, that is another ext4 partition of the SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having done some more research I found out that [Fedora 16 experienced the same problem](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=272249). I consequently [filed a bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/999742) and from the subsequent discussion it appears that **the behaviour is due to the *hot-pluggable* nature of SATA devices**.

Comment: You may also be interested in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133802/disable-removable-device-notification-for-hard-drives and the GNOME bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660595

Answer (score 2):

Rather than additionally mounting subdirectories of an already mounted drive let me suggest you mount it separately. You may then create a symlink to that directory in your HOME to make it accessible.

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/runtime
```

Then mount your SSD partition to `` `media/runtime `` or edit your `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=[uuid] /media/runtime ext4 relatime,errors=remount-ro,discard 0 2
```

Replace [uuid] by the UUID of your drive. To grant access to this partition create a symlink in your HOME:

```
ln -s /media/runtime /home/mac/
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion, that I followed and made me discover a few more mounting options... However, even following your advice, the problem still persist. The partition shows up as a removable media.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Pretty oldish now but I believe, should you wish, you can disable the hotplug features through kernel options (re-compiling a kernel).